# Ввод команды в консоль node js из программы на c++

Tags: c++, node.js, winapi

Запускается процесс ноды из проги на c++

```
char fname[] = "D:/node.exe";
char cfname[] = "D:/node";

STARTUPINFO cif;
ZeroMemory(&cif, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

CreateProcessA(NULL, fname, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, NULL,
    cfname, &cif, &pi);
```

Чтобы запустить скрип на выполнение можно просто заменить "D:/node.exe" на "D:/node.exe run", но в таком случае файл с кодом придется записать на жесткий диск и он может быть прочитан посторонним. Еще можно выполнить код посредством ввода его в консоль ноды, вот только как этот ввод сделать программно?

Пробовал по этому примеру http://www.sources.ru/cpp/using_anonymous_pipes.shtml, с обычной консолью все работает, но с окном ноды не хочет...

Comment: А что, параметр `-e` уже не работает? `node -e 'console.log("what?")'`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это подойдет, но хотелось бы узнать почему нода не хочет принимать сообщения из замененного StdIn

Comment: Там наверняка есть проверка на isTTY

Comment: Ещё можно использовать `https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html`